# Drawing two PCBs in Altium

Tags: pcb, altium

I'm doing a project in Altium. In my project, I need to have PCBs in two different places to be connected to each other, but I don't know how to do it.  Does such a thing happen? How do I divide my schematic into two different PCBs?

Comment: I think you may be over-thinking this. Once you have your parts in the PCB area you can segregate them into two PCBs as you wish. How you draw the schematic so that parts in one physical half are segregated from another is purely down to personal preference between "no segregation" to full "different page" segregation.

Comment: I need to design the power and buttons components on one board and the main circuit on a separate board. I'm connecting them with wires. But I don't know how to separate the two circuits on the PCB.

Comment: Altium has a layer that you can put board edges and cut-outs on. These delimit your two boards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [multi-board feature](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/designing-systems-with-multiple-boards-ad?version=18.1) (in more recent versions of Altium) or just copy/paste parts of your full schematic into two or more individual schematics, add connectors or whatever to interconnect the boards, and then create individual boards from those partial schematics. Or you can create the multiple boards as one "PCB" with cut lines (V-groove, CNC routing, mouse bites, or even $$ tooling up for a cut/push die) on the composite PCB, to be separated at some later point. Which is better depends on your preference, to some extent on the relative complexity of the boards, and how you are planning on manufacturing the boards.

For example, I have made designs where several boards in a set were populated and tested in one operation and then the individual boards were separated and assembled. If the boards are appropriate size you can even panelize the board sets. In other cases, you may wish to use different technologies for the boards (multilayer or even HDI for a board containing dense high pin-count parts and cheaper boards for panel controls, sensors or power supply), in which case the boards will be manufactured in separate processes (maybe separate factories) and brought together much later.